# Replace single quotes in a text is surrounded single quotes

Tags: powershell, regexp-replace

I try to make an escaping of single quotes in a text. Need to replace single quotes in the text with double single quotes. Problem is that need keep some specific single quotes. Text contains regularity in the text: `text1 ('text2','te'xt',...,'text')`. If the text in parentheses contains single quote or quotes, they should be replaced with double single quotes.
`'te'xt'` - > `'te''xt'`

Source text:

```
Some text ('Changes [delete [object] = '1']', 'Changes')
```

Desired result:

```
Some text ('Changes [delete [object] = ''1'']', 'Changes')
```

I started from an easier text:

```
'Changes [delete [object] = '1']'
```

My the best achievement `'.`*`(').`*`'`  is finding one of single quote

https://regex101.com/r/OSw4G0/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex might work for you, without having more examples of how the text can look like it's hard to tell how robust it will be.

```bash
@(
    "text1 ('text2','te'xt',...,'text')"
    "Some text ('Changes [delete [object] = '1']', 'Changes')"
) -replace "(?<![\()]|\s?,|,\s?)'(?![\()]|\s?,|,\s?)", '$0$0'
```

The output produced from above example is as you expected:

```
text1 ('text2','te''xt',...,'text')
Some text ('Changes [delete [object] = ''1'']', 'Changes')
```

See https://regex101.com/r/jxJebK/1 for details.